# Entity Framework multiple data models

Tags: .net, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

I have projection using EF 4.0 with self tracking entities it has one data model and everything is working fine. No I need to add a second model to to connect to a different database. As soon as I add the second model into the project the build fails.
I get errors like these for all the entities in the first model.

```
Error   12  The type 'Entities.InvoiceFile' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DataServices.SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions.ApplyChanges<TEntity>(System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity>, TEntity)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Entities.InvoiceFile' to 'DataServices.IObjectWithChangeTracker'
```

Any ideas?

If I remove the POCO entities for the second model the project builds fine but then I get runtime errors like this

```
Test method DataServicesTest.TestStatements threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'Entities.Currency'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's not easy to do this in a single project.  The easy solution is to create a new project only for the data model, then add a reference and use it that way.

Right click on the solution, choose Add -> New Project, choose a class library project, in the new project add a new Entity Framework model.

Comment: @Satish - It's namespace issues.  There's no easy solution, other than putting it in another project.

Comment: EF probes the assembly for classes that match the names they're looking for